# Difference between convex function's images

Tags: calculus, limits

While solving my homework, a thought came to my head which I couldn't prove but seemed very natural to me:

Given that I have a differentiable function $f$, continuous at a closed interval $[a,b]$, can be differentiated twice at the open interval $(a, b)$ and to any $x\in(a, b)$ the second derivative is positive.

Also,
$$\lim_{x\to{b^-}}f(x) = \infty$$

I want to show that even as I take very close values $x_2,x_1\in(a,b)$ such that $x_2 > x_2$ but also very close to $b$, the difference between the images of those values approaches infinity.

I want to prove it for two sequences $X_n\to{b}$ and $\frac{n}{n+1}X_n$ and show, using Lagrange's mean value theorem, that $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(X_n)-f(\frac{n}{n+1}X_n)) = \infty$$

I did not manage to prove it which drives me nuts because according to my intuition it should work.

Answer (score 1):

I would first try to show that the increasing function $f'(x)$ cannot be bounded from above by a constant $M$ (proving that by contradiction). Here is the proof of that:

If the increasing function $f'$ is bounded from above by $M$ and we pick a domain value $ x_0$ where $f'(x_0)>0$ then for all $x>x_0$,  the mean value theorem tells us that 
$f(x)- f(x_0)= f'(c_x) (x-x_0) \leq M (x- x_0)$, where $c_x\in (x_0, x)$. Thus the graph of $f(x)$ is trapped underneath the graph of a linear function of slope $M$, and clearly that contradicts the assumption that $f(x)\to +\infty$  as $x\to b$.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I tried to do, but I didn't manage to show what I needed